# How to hide bean type in snakeyaml

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

This code will output:(YAML)

--- !!org.test.bean.Person

address: 4011 16th Ave S

.....

Can hide my bean type(org.test.bean.Person) anyway !?
(prefer to use snakeyaml config...i can't find it..)

thanks!!

```
public static void dumpYAML(){
    Constructor constructor = new Constructor(Person.class);
    TypeDescription personDescription = new TypeDescription(Person.class);
    personDescription.putListPropertyType("phone", Tel.class);
    constructor.addTypeDescription(personDescription);

    Yaml yaml = new Yaml(constructor);
    Person person = (Person) yaml.load(makeYAML());

    DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
    options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
    options.setCanonical(false); // display bean member attribute
    options.setExplicitStart(true); // display --- start

    yaml = new Yaml(options);
    String output = yaml.dump(person);
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer`, set `Tag.MAP` to hide the root tag.

```
Representer representer = new Representer();
representer.addClassTag(Person.class, Tag.MAP);
```

Answer (score 12):

You can extend Representer to 'sneakily' inject any non-registered bean class as Map.

```
public class MapRepresenter extends Representer {

    @Override
    protected MappingNode representJavaBean(Set<Property> properties, Object javaBean) {
        if (!classTags.containsKey(javaBean.getClass()))
            addClassTag(javaBean.getClass(), Tag.MAP);

        return super.representJavaBean(properties, javaBean);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Some more clarity on using `org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer`, it needs to be passed to YAML:

```java
DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
options.setPrettyFlow(true);

Representer representer = new Representer(options);
representer.addClassTag(Person.class, Tag.MAP); // Put your class here

Yaml yaml = new Yaml(representer, options);
String output = yaml.dump(person); // Put your object here
System.out.println(output);
```