# Avoid the JavaBean Root Tags in SnakeYaml dumping

Tags: java, yaml, dump, snakeyaml

When I dump a instance of the following class:

```java
class BrooklynApplicationEntity{
    private String id;
    private String location;
    private String name;
    List<BrooklynServiceEntity> services;

    //getters and setters
    ...
}
```

Using the next code:

```
 DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
 options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
 options.setCanonical(false);
 options.setDefaultScalarStyle(DumperOptions.ScalarStyle.PLAIN);
 SkipEmptyAndNullRepresenter skipEmptyAndNullRepresenter=
     new SkipEmptyAndNullRepresenter();

 Yaml yaml=new Yaml(skipEmptyAndNullRepresenter, options);
 yaml.dump(this.getBrooklynApplicationEntity(), file);
```

I obtain the next yaml.

```
!!org.tomat.translate.brooklyn.entity.BrooklynApplicationEntity
id: dbApp
location: localhost
name: DatabaseApp
services:
- !!org.tomat.translate.brooklyn.entity.JBossBrooklynService
  brooklynConfigProperties:
    port.http: 80+
  id: JBossMainWebServer
  location: AWS
  name: JBoss Main Web Server
- !!org.tomat.translate.brooklyn.entity.JBossBrooklynService
  id: JBossSecondWebServer
  location: localhost
  name: JBoss
```

I want to avoid the TAGs in the output YAML, so I have added the next instructions,
how it has described in [How to hide bean type in snakeyaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246027/how-to-hide-bean-type-in-snakeyaml?rq=1), [ImplicitTagsTest](https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/source/browse/src/test/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/ImplicitTagsTest.java).

```java
    skipEmptyAndNullRepresenter.addClassTag(JBossAgnosticElement.class, Tag.MAP);
    skipEmptyAndNullRepresenter.addClassTag(JBossAgnosticElement.class, Tag.SEQ);
```

However, the TAGs `!!org.tomat.translate.brooklyn.entity.BrooklynApplicationEntity` and `!!org.tomat.translate.brooklyn.entity.JBossBrooklynService` are not deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this questions.
When I add a implicit tag (e.g. TAG.Map) to a class, I have to use the complete class name.
For example, for avoiding the `!!org.tomat.translate.brooklyn.entity.JBossAgnosticElement` it is necessary the next instruction.

```java
skipEmptyAndNullRepresenter.addClassTag(
    org.tomat.translate.brooklyn.entity.JBossAgnosticElement.class, Tag.MAP);
```

instead of

```
skipEmptyAndNullRepresenter.addClassTag(JBossAgnosticElement.class, Tag.MAP);
```

Comment: Looks like you had the wrong `JBossAgnosticElement`. With the right import, it works perfectly without using the fully qualified class name. With the right import, those statements would also be completely equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //write seperate function to remove tag comments !!sometest.Trades from the yaml file as it will cause issue while reading it
            Representer representer = new Representer() {
                @Override
                protected NodeTuple representJavaBeanProperty(Object javaBean, Property property, Object propertyValue, Tag customTag) {
                    // if value of property is null, ignore it.
                    if (int.class.equals(property.getType())) {
                        return null;
                    } else {
                        return super.representJavaBeanProperty(javaBean, property, propertyValue, customTag);
                    }
                }
            };
            representer.addClassTag(sometest.Trades.class, Tag.MAP);
            Yaml yaml1 = new Yaml(representer, options);
 Writer output;
            output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFilePath, true));
            yaml1.dump(trades, output);
            output.close();
```